# Probability of intersection of two events

Tags: probability

The probability of the intersection of A and B is `P(A) * P(B)`.

Example:

There are 5 cars:

- 3 trucks, 2 vans
- 1 truck is red
- 1 van is red
- 2 cars are red
- 1 car is red AND a truck

Thus:

```
P(T) = 3 / 5 = 0.6 # if one car is chosen at random, 0.6 chance it'll be a truck
P(R) = 2 / 5 = 0.4 # if one car is chosen at random, 0.4 chance it'll be red
```

My question:

Since only 1 truck is red, isn't the probability that a car chosen a random will be a red truck = `1 / 5 = 0.2`?

But `P(T) * P(R) = 0.24`

Comment: Notice that in order for your first sentence to be true, the events would have to be **independent**.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Thanks. What in this example makes the two events not independent? Or is my formulation just a single event (selecting a car at random)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability of the intersection of two events A and B is $P(A) * P(B)$ when A and B are independent. In this case the event "picking a truck" changes the probability of the event "the picked car is red" red from $\frac{2}{5}$ to $P(R|T) = \frac{1}{3}$, so they are not independent.

In this formula $P(R|T)$ means "probability that a random car is red knowing (the | symbol) that it is a truck". You actually proved that they are not independent when you saw that $P(T) * P(R)$ differs from the probability of picking at random a red truck.

This is called conditional probability:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability

More info on independent events:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)